# C# Filter List of Active Directory Users & return Active/Enabled Users

Tags: c#, active-directory

I have a list of Users being returned from AD and I need to filter them to just return the Active users. This is my code, but it's not returning any users. After extensive googling, I'm at a loss as to what's missing;

```
        public static List<Models.ToolUser> ActiveUsers()
    {
        int unlimitedAccess;
        //string userAccountControl;
        string listEntry;
        string fName;
        string lName;
        string unlimitedAccessGroup;

//This is getting the List of Users that I need to filter
        List<Models.ToolUser> activeUserList = UIDal.GetFullWindowsUserList();

        try
        {
            string filter = "(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(!userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))";
            string[] propertiesToLoad = new string[1] { "name" };

            using (DirectoryEntry de = GetDirectoryEntryWithGc())
            using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(de, filter, propertiesToLoad))
            using (SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll())
            {
                foreach (SearchResult result in results)
                {
                    unlimitedAccess = 0;
                    fName = result.Properties["givenName"][0].ToString();
                    lName = result.Properties["sn"][0].ToString();
                    listEntry = fName + " " + lName;

                    var name = result.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString();

                    var u = new ToolUser
                    {
                        ToolUserId = 0,
                        DomainAccount = result.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString(),
                        FirstName = fName,
                        LastName = lName,
                        LoginId = "pc-" + result.Properties["sAMAccountName"][0].ToString(),
                        UnlimitedAccess = unlimitedAccess > 0,
                    };

                    activeUserList.Add(u);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        return activeUserList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empty catch blocks are the devil. You should at least log the exception before continuing.

In this case, your empty catch block is hiding what's really going on. You're getting an "Index was out of range" exception here:

```
fName = result.Properties["givenName"][0].ToString();
```

Because `result.Properties["givenName"]` is an empty collection (there is no element at index `0`). That's happening because of this:

```
string[] propertiesToLoad = new string[1] { "name" };
```

You are telling the search to only return the `name` attribute for the objects found, but then you go on to use `givenName`, `sn` and `sAMAccountName`. You need to tell it to return those attributes if you intend to use them:

```
string[] propertiesToLoad = new string[3] { "givenName", "sn", "sAMAccountName" };
```

That said, `givenName` and `sn` are not required attributes. If those attributes are empty on any of the accounts found, then they will not appear in the `Properties` collection at all and you will run into the same exception again. So you should test that those attributes are actually there before trying to use them. For example, this will check and set the variables to an empty string if the attribute doesn't exist:

```
fName = result.Properties.Contains("givenName") ? result.Properties["givenName"][0].ToString() : "";
lName = result.Properties.Contains("sn") ? result.Properties["sn"][0].ToString() : "";
```

Comment: You're right, logging the exception has helped. I'm still trying to get only the active users but your answer has helped!

Comment: It depends what you mean by "active". You are already finding all enabled accounts, but enabled doesn't mean that they're actively used. If you want to find accounts that are being used, look at the [`lastLogonTimestamp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-lastlogontimestamp) attribute.

Comment: I'm wanting to return any account with the code 512 from an existing list of users, essentially filtering that list.

Comment: What do you mean by "code 512"? Where `userAccountControl` is `512`?

Comment: Yes, where the accounts is a normal active account

Comment: Are you sure that's what you want? The [`userAccountControl` attribute](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/305144/how-to-use-useraccountcontrol-to-manipulate-user-account-properties) is a bit flag, meaning that each bit in the binary value is a flag meaning a different thing. If you search specifically for `512`, you will not find an active account that has, say, the "don't expire password" flag set.

Comment: The way you are already doing it is the correct way to find all enabled accounts (accounts that do not have the 2nd bit set - the 2nd bit means "disabled").

Comment: In that case this will work fine. Thanks Gabriel :)